# Scripts being deleted by AV

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So I have been building a bat/powershell tool to make my job easier. It is full of scripts to fix, modify, and configure systems to the company standard for our clients. Over the past 6 months I have just disabled AV programs that falsely detect my script as malicious.

I would like to tackle this issue and switch to a way to work without having files deleted as I use them when I forget to disable an AV.

The system primarily works in Powershell, but as we deal with a lot of Windows 7 machines still, I have to have a batch program to initiate the script to install the powershell module. At the same time, it copies all the files to run the program into a folder under C:.
I have looked into a bat2exe solution, but I have everything broken up into tiny files for ease of use for myself and powershell. I also cant just compile batch and powershell into one exe from my understanding.

Am I better off just rewriting it into a compiled language, or is the a way to have my little project work around the false positives of the AV's?

Comment: Are you signing your scripts?

Comment: No. Can I do that for script that is going to run on a computer one time?

Comment: If you really don't want to sign your PS scripts, or you are using a batch script, you will need to configure your A/V whitelist appropriately. If you need help with that, https://superuser.com/ would be the best place to ask.

Comment: So I have looked into signing the scripts. I am still working on and modifying my script as I develop to the final solution. Official signing doesnt make sense at this point and self-signing wont work on any computer other than the one that creates the signature.
So far I have been using vbs to create an run a batch in admin to bypass execution policy and run powershell. Its long winded and painful, but works 80% of the time. It seems like for my particular case, signing wont resolve this problem

Comment: What does Windows 7 have to do with this?

Comment: Windows 7, by default, doesn't have the correct version of powershell. I use the batch to install the powershell update.

Comment: Doesn't updating WMF require a reboot to finish applying? Someone keep me honest here but I think you can update Powershell from within a Powershell script because of this, though you would need to initiate a reboot. I don't update PS enough myself to know if this is the case offhand though.

Comment: Updating within powershell 2.0 gives me an idea on how to resolve this. Thanks @BendertheGreatest

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer here is to sign your scripts. The specific process to configure A/V appropriately may vary between different A/V tools, but signing your Powershell scripts is a solid method to verify the integrity of your Powershell code.

For batch scripts, I'm not sure there is a way outside of running them from a directory or filepath whitelisted by your A/V.

[This blog post](https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/5/powershell-basics-execution-policy-part-1.html) contains some good info on self-signing your Powershell scripts, or using a certificate from AD Certificate Services.

[Here is Microsoft's official doc on Powershell script signing as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-6).

**Update**: If you are still developing your script and are not ready to sign it as indicated by one of your comments, temporarily disabling A/V is a bit heavy-handed. Typically on development systems, engineers add (or if they don't have access, have their IT dept. add) their project/source folder(s) to the A/V whitelist, which should prevent A/V from interfering with your development code.